# Using virt-install and http preseed to do unattended ubuntu 10.04 install

Tags: ubuntu, automated-install, libvirt

The virt-install command line I used is below

> sudo virt-install kvm ubuntu -v sudo virt-install -v -n golden-egg -r
>   256 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/golden-egg.qcow2,size=5
>   --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntulucid --force --cdrom=temp/ubuntu-10.04.1-server-amd64.iso --virt-type qemu --connect=qemu:///system --extra-args="interface=eth0 hostname=goldenegg domain=foo.internal
>   netcfg/get_ipaddress=192.168.1.15 netcfg/get_netmask=255.255.255.0
>   netcfg/get_gateway=192.168.1.1 netcfg/get_nameservers=192.168.1.1
>   netcfg/disable_dhcp=true auto url=http://192.168.1.100/"

The ubuntu installer is launching but it goes into interactive mode. I've set a small webserver up to serve the preseed file and verified that it is being served on the url specified. However the server doesn't get hit on VM creation and there are no errors in the VM console or anything else I am able to go by.

Any suggests on how to proceed to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can only use `--extra-args` when using `--location`, not when using `--cdrom`

See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=622661

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use tcpdump on your server to see if your virtual machine is actually requesting the preseed file, and you can see the URL it's using.  I normally specify the url as http://server/path/to/preseed.conf

Answer (score 1):

i believe you should be using `preseed/url=` instead of `url=` and you should also include `preseed/url/checksum=` which IIRC contains md5 of the preseed file

Comment: According to [Aliases useful with preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/amd64/preseed-using.html#preseed-aliases) the `url=` argument is fine, though there is no alias for the checksum (which is unfortunate).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "priority=critical locale=en_US" to the boot arguments.